# Can't load tidyverse library

Tags: r, tidyverse

Just upgraded R and RStudio to

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness
```

The rstudio version is

```
Version 1.0.143 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.
```

Then I install the tidyverse package

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

results in

```
trying URL 'https://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/tidyverse_1.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 42211 bytes (41 KB)
downloaded 41 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6vaNT1\downloaded_packages
```

Everything OK.

Now, when trying to load the tidyverse library:

```
> library("tidyverse")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘cellranger’
```

Fail.

I can load all the packages individually, but for some reason not the tidyverse package.

Comment: First thing to try: `install.packages("cellranger")`.

Comment: thanks @ neilfws, problem solved. Was strange since I tried with dependency = TRUE before. Thanks again

Comment: Instead of editing the solution into the question, please leave an answer below.

Comment: thanks @josliber , answer added

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to install a dependency:

```
install.packages("cellranger")
```

(answered in comments by @neilfws)

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve your problem

```
install.packages('cellranger')
install.packages('tidyverse', type = 'binary')
```